# A clean way for adding variable-length values to data frame by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am creating random data.  It should contain variables `id` and `val` where values cannot overlap within a single id but can overlap across id-s.  Different id-s have different number of values `n`.  I can create the desired result manually as:

```
n <- c(3,2,4)
data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:3], n), 
           val=c(sample(10, n[1]), 
                 sample(10, n[2]), 
                 sample(10, n[3])))
  id val
1  a   5
2  a  10
3  a   4
4  b   9
5  b  10
6  c  10
7  c   5
8  c   2
9  c   9
```

I can also imagine different solutions involving looping over groups and using `rbind`, or using `rep`-ing the id-s by corresponding number of times.  But all such approaches feel dirty, and may not scale to many variables and large data.

Are there any cleaner ways to achieve it?  Something like (in dplyrish):

```
data.frame(id=letters[1:3]) %>%
   mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarize_into_df(id=id, val=sample(10, n[i]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through `n` with `lapply`, create a list column using `sample`, then unnest it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n <- c(3,2,4)
data.frame(id = letters[1:length(n)]) %>% 
    mutate(val = lapply(n, sample, x=10)) %>% 
    unnest

#  id val
#1  a   9
#2  a   4
#3  a  10
#4  b   4
#5  b   8
#6  c   5
#7  c  10
#8  c   8
#9  c   2
```

Or without using any package, which is very close to what you have, just replace manual construct with `unlist(lapply(...))`:

```
data.frame(id = rep(letters[1:length(n)], n), 
           val = unlist(lapply(n, sample, x=10)))
```

Comment: unnest works well, I was not aware of that, thanks!  The other solution get a little more muddy if there are several id variables.